# referring to jsfiddle.net with POST data

Tags: javascript, php, post, jsfiddle, amcharts

In the site

```
http://www.amcharts.com/demos/
```

I found that they are providing way to  edit the demos in jsfiddle but for every demo the jsfiddle.net link remains the same as follows

[jsfiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)

I guess they are referring jsfiddle.net with some post data. Though i'm not sure about that. Any idea how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/post.html) is what you're looking for. It describes the ways to display a fiddle from query data. Here's an excerpt explaining why the URL remains the same.

> Use library/pure for no framework:
>
> URL: jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/